# Finite Complement Topology of a finite set

Tags: general-topology

The finite complement definition is given as

> Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal{T}_f$ be the collection of all
> subsets of $U$ of $X$ such that $X - U$ either is finite or is all of
> $X$. Then $\mathcal{T}_f$ is a topology on X, called the finite complement.

All the examples I have seen so far consider $X$ to be $\mathbb{R}$. I was wondering what happens if $X$ itself is a finite set. Is finite complement of $X$, the power set of $X$ itself? Since the definition states $\mathcal{T}_f$ is a topology on $X$, I know $X$ should be in $\mathcal{T}_f$, if $X$ is finite. I would appreciate if you could provide examples.

Comment: If $X$ is finite, then the finite complement topology is the ([discrete](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteTopology.html)) one where every subset of $X$ is open

Answer (score 1):

Indeed if $X$ is a finite set, all subsets have finite complement so all subsets are open and $X$ is just the discrete topology.

The first interesting case is where $X$ is countably infinite.